# dynamically create variable from json object

Tags: json, node.js, variables

```
var a={LogGroupName:'/sam/xxx/ab/xxx/ayb/lob-star',LogStreamName:'tsy98',S3_Bucket:'abc'};
var array=[a];
console.log(array);
[ { LogGroupName: '/sam/xxx/ab/xxx/ayb/lob-star',LogStreamName: 'tsy98',S3_Bucket: 'abc' } ]
```

Would require to dynamically find the length of the array and variablize the key value from the json object.

Output needed:

```
LogGroupName=/sam/xxx/ab/xxx/ayb/lob-star
console.log(LogGroupName);
```

Need help.

Comment: You don't have any arrays anywhere in the code you posted. Although you *could* use `eval` for this, this is really an X/Y problem, what are you *actually* trying to achieve?

Comment: please find the updated question to make it clear. I would like all the variables in the json object to be initialized.

Comment: so you are saying its hard to initialize the key and value as a variable where                                                                    
   var key = value;